# Regex match lines until the first empty line

Tags: regex

Looking for a simple regexp which will match all lines until the first empty line.

I tried the following regexp but it does not handle all cases.

Here is the regexp:

```
/[\s\S]*(?=\r{2,})/
```

For example, this case: https://regex101.com/r/lW7IQ8/1

Comment: For what language/tool ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^[\s\S]*?(?=\n{2,})
```

*? lazy match, add ^ for only match the 1th one.

Answer (score 4):

If it is really `PHP` (`PCRE` and the like) you are trying this into, you might very well get along with:

```
^(?:.+\R)+
```

in `multiline` mode, [**see your modified demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lW7IQ8/2) (clue here is to require at least *one* character, thus not allowing empty lines).

---

For `JavaScript` the pattern is similar

```
^(?:.+[\n\r])+
```

See [**a demo for the latter**](https://regex101.com/r/lW7IQ8/2) on regex101.com as well.